# Saving remote files using Eclipse RSE

Tags: eclipse, sftp, eclipse-rse

When I connect to a remote server using Eclipse's RSE I can upload and edit a file via sftp and I can save it locally but I can't figure out how save it back to the remote server. I can't even tell if this functionality is available or not.

Help!

Comment: you said: *** I can upload and edit a file via sftp*** if you are able to upload then its same to saving file on remote server.

Comment: That's what I figured. It saves the file locally then when I go back to the remote server and have a look at the file it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about sftp but with ssh, I'm positive the files loaded from the remote server are also saved remotely. I would imagine the same holds true for sftp.  My understanding of RSE is that it lies on top of ECF (Eclipse Communcation Facility) and thereby provides different transport mechanism (ssh, sftp) to achieve the same end result.  Among which editing remote files.

Comment: Would there be anything preventing such a transfer? My iptable seems to be setup correctly. What about error logs I can check?

Comment: The log is in workspace/myworkspace/.log and you can also access it as a view (window => show view => error log).  However, I'm under the impression that you are not using RSE in the same way as I do.  Do you create a local file and upload it ? or do you browse remote files through RSE, load it in the editor and save it (that's what I do with ssh, you could try with ssh to see if this is related to sftp).

Comment: I'm browsing for the file through RSE. When I save it it gets saved locally in the RemoteSystemsTempFiles folder. When I close the file and reopen it it appears to open from that folder (there's no delay like a file uploading). I wonder if I'm saving it the wrong way... is there a special option or simply File > Save